# C# - Loop no while

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho uma função em C# que checa se um download foi concluído consultando se a existência do arquivo `.crdownload` é verdadeira.

Caso este não exista, atribuo um booleano true na variável desse while, e teoricamente deveria encerrar este loop. Porém não acontece.

```
private bool CheckDownloadByPartialName_v2(string partialName, string path)
{
    bool success = false;
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    while (!success)
    {
        bool downloading = directory.GetFiles()
                                  .Where(file => file.Name.StartsWith(partialName))
                                  .Where(file => file.Extension == ".crdownload")
                                  .SingleOrDefault()
                                  .Exists;

        if (!downloading)
            success = true;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Outro problema que estou encarando neste código é que, quando o arquivo com extensão `.crdownload` não existe (final do loop) meu código da uma exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Provavelmente causada por causa do `.SingleOrDefault()` da minha query LINQ.

Alguém consegue me ajudar com essas coisas?

Comment: È um absurdo fazer isso, vai detonar o processador e disco para nada, você tem que usar o https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: Tenho noção de que isso pode utilizar bastante processamento, mas é apenas um pequeno robô que visita o painel de controle da minha VPN e faz o download dos logs de acesso para um diretório externo.

Comment: Não consigo entender por quê o loop se repete após declarar a variável `sucess` como `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a expressão LINQ não faz sentido. Você está consultando **itens que existem** em um diretório e depois usando o `Exists` pra validar se o item existe (mas a consulta já fez esse trabalho).

Então, quando não existir alguém com a extensão `crdownload` o retorno `SingleOrDefault` vai ser `null` e por isso acontece a exceção.

Você simplificar a expressão pra esta abaixo:

```
var downloading = directory.GetFiles().Any(f => f.Name.StartsWith(partialName) &&
                                                f.Extension == ".crdownload");
```

Note que, [como já foi pontuado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/447973/c-loop-no-while#comment859656_447973), isso é um absurdo gigantesco. Existem API's do .NET prontas e otimizadas para este tipo de trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Os comentários estão certos seu código não faz sentido, não leve a mal.

```
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Tools
{
    public static class DownloadChecker
    {
        public static bool CheckDownloadByPartialName_v2(string partialName, string path)
        {
            // Use uma expressão regular:
            Regex regex = new Regex($"{partialName}.*");

            bool complete;

            for (; ; )
            {
                //Verifique se existe algum arquivo que corresponde à expressão:
                complete = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.crdownload").Where(file => regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file))).Count() == 0;

                if (complete)
                    return complete;

                // Espere um pouco para não colocar seu processador em 100%:
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var complete = Tools.DownloadChecker.CheckDownloadByPartialName_v2("nome parcial", @"c:\caminho\do\arquivo");
```

Lembrando que talvez essa não seja a melhor forma de fazer isso, pois isso bloqueia a Thread atual, use um Task se possível.

E com um conhecimento básico em expressões regulares pode modificar a expressão para sua necessidade. E se o `partialName` contiver caracteres reservados à expressão regular será necessário escapá-los.

Se você souber o nome do arquivo exato fica mais fácil com:

```
File.Exists("arquivo");
```

O comentário do Maniero é bem válido, pode ser uma opção melhor, pois assim você diminui o número de consultas no sistema de arquivos.